# Flutter function called infinitely in build

Tags: flutter, dart

I am making an app which loads the CSV and show the table on the screen but the load function is being called infinitely in the build state can anyone know how to fix it I wanted to call only once but my code called it many times.

Here is the console screenshot:
[image: a busy cat]

Here is the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:csv/csv.dart';
import 'dart:async' show Future;
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;

class TableLayout extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TableLayoutState createState() => _TableLayoutState();
}
class _TableLayoutState extends State<TableLayout> {

  List<List<dynamic>> data = [];

  loadAsset() async {
    final myData = await rootBundle.loadString("asset/dreamss.csv");
    List<List<dynamic>> csvTable = CsvToListConverter().convert(myData);

    return csvTable;
  }
  void load() async{
    var newdata = await loadAsset();
    setState(() {
      data = newdata;
    });
    print("am i still being called called ");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    load();

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Apps"),),
        //floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton( onPressed: load,child: Icon(Icons.refresh),),
        body: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),),
        Table(
          border: TableBorder.all(width: 1.0,color: Colors.black),
          children: data.map((item){
            return TableRow(
              children: item.map((row){
                return Text(row.toString(),style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0,fontWeight: FontWeight.w900),);
              }).toList(),
            );
          }).toList(),
        ),
    ]),
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: call `load();` inside `initState()` method

Comment: @pskink yeah i tried it but it  doesn't work

Comment: yes, it works...

Comment: @pskink is right, you should override `initState()` method and put your `load();` inside it.

Comment: @pskink  yeah i did it and  i got red screen  and in the console i get this error mesage. ``` Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 1003 pos 12: '_debugLifecycleState == _StateLifecycle.created': is not true.```

Comment: did you call `super.initState()` as your android studio says?

Comment: yeah  super.initState();

Comment: did you restart your entire app? not hot reload

Comment: @pskink  yeah I tried  restarting the app it doesn't work here is the screenshot of the error log [image](https://i.ibb.co/X49xLLC/1.jpg)  and here is the screenshot of the initstate code [image2](https://ibb.co/b1fvgSP)

Comment: first call `super` then call `load`

Comment: You don't have to call `initState()` in your `build()` method, I added a solution, take a look.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad  and pskink thanks for your help I got it.

Comment: Why build() is getting called infinite no of times?

Comment: @shahanakareen because it is called every time when the widget is built(or every time UI chages) not indefinitely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution.

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  load(); // use it here
}


@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(...); // no need to call initState() here
}
```